# looping declaration code improvement for django

Tags: python, django, join, declaration

I have 2 lists where rakam = 1 to 9  sakla_l = sakla,sakla,sakla etc 9 times.
I want to join these 2 lists to become sakla0,sakla1,sakla2 etc till sakla9
then I want to declare all as one like

```
sakla0 =1 
sakla1= 1
sakla2= 1  etc..
```

I am accessing these declarations from below parts of my code now I declared manually but I didn't like to code and I am trying to improve with for loop but no success searched a lot within stackoverflow but I can't find nothing similar to that.Please don't say it's duplicate question because it's not.
My aim not to print these items.My aim is to have that declaration of these items equal to 1.

```
import string
rakam= list(range(10))
sakla_l =["sakla"] * 10
for i in range(10):
    j_list=sakla_l[i].join(str(i))
    j_list[i] = 1
print(j_list)
```

My working undesired code is below:

```
    sakla0=1
    sakla1=1
    sakla2=1
    sakla3=1
    sakla4=1
    sakla5=1
    sakla6=1
    sakla7=1
    sakla8=1
    sakla9=1
```

You might ask why you need to declare, the reason I am hiding some tables or unhiding some tables within the django html template based on these values.

Comment: I don't see why this is not a duplicate of the standard advice to use a list or dictionary. If you want to claim it isn't, please explain in more detail why you need separate items. What *exactly* are you doing in the template that needs them?

Comment: If sakla0 = 0 then i am unhiding the table if not it stays hidden.

Comment: I need to default declare as 1 so that they stay hidden

Comment: But why not `if sakla_l[0] == 0` then it stays hidden? *Why* do you need separate values?

Comment: I have 10 different places to be hidden with different conditions

Comment: Yes, and? Why can't you use different indexes into the list at different points?